# google map not loaded with api key

Tags: google-maps

I want to show a location on google map but nothing show :

```
<script src="****/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAvUNbVZUPT_8V-VMCcfI9aex3ygZO4J7U"></script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Google map
    if ($('#map-canvas').length) {
        var
            GOOGLE_MAP_LAT = 35.706291,
            GOOGLE_MAP_LNG = 51.316624;
        var map,
            service;
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(GOOGLE_MAP_LAT, GOOGLE_MAP_LNG);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                marker.setMap(map);

                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setCenter(latlng);
    }
});
```

my html code :

```
        <div id="#map-canvas" style="width: 300px;height: 400px"> </div>
```

to see my website:

http://www.eleconf.ir/

my console log is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html, the ID of div is given as #map-canvas. # is not required.